# How to query RavenDB for document containing nested object of specified type

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have a RavenDB query using index and I need to add condition checking nested objects type (these objects aren't separate documents)

```
entries = session.Query<result, index>()
  /* some conditions here */
  .Where(x => x.Messages.Any(m => m.GetType() == typeof(MyMessage)))
  .ToList();
```

Raven tells me, that he doesn't know how to translate GetType. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Does `MyMessage` have a property you could query for a predictable value?

Comment: No. We have different message types for template choose. This is the problem - all massages have the same set of properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After long research I found the solution.

I added field to index:

```
MessageTypes = entry.Messages.Select(m => AsDocument(m)["$type"].ToString())
```

`AsDocument()` returns `RavenJObject` which contains all properties including `$type`. With that property indexed, asking for certain type is quite simple